# Parse table names from a bunch SQL statements

Tags: python, sql, regex, linux, oracle

I have an table with thousands of SQL statements in a column called Queries. Any ideas on how to get just the table names from the statements by using a regular expression?

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It are you withholding the answer or just commenting?

Comment: In order to get a closer or accurate response, you need to provide more details. Any example ? or the issue you are facing ?

Comment: If you want to do it from a select statement you should be creating  a SQL parser in it, using regex or wahtever. For example you will have to parse table references and joins.

Comment: Regular expression only?  Probably not possible, especially as Oracle allows CTEs (inline view declarations).  I might stick _just_ the table containing your queries into a new db instance, then tell it to execute them all, parsing out the table names from the error message (standard location in string!) - and creating them, obviously, as statements usually contain more than one table.

Comment: Do the statements have a predictable pattern? For example, are table names always preceded by "FROM" or "JOIN"? I'm aware that this isn't necessarily the case with all possible queries, but do you know if it's true for the ones you have?

Answer (score 7):

Were it me, I would tend to try to approach the problem a different way.  Rather than writing a SQL parser (which would require much more than a regular expression unless you can guarantee that all the SQL statements using a very tiny subset of the available SQL grammar), I would tend to generate a query plan for each object and then query `PLAN_TABLE` to see the objects that Oracle has to hit.  You'd need to do an additional lookup for index accesses to find out what table the index is defined on but that should be reasonably straightforward.

If you go down this path, however, you'll be retrieving the base tables that your query actually touches rather than whatever views the queries may actually refer to.  That is, if you have a query `SELECT * FROM view_1` and `view_1`, in turn, is defined as a query against `table_a` and `table_b`, only `table_a` and `table_b` will be part of the plan.  And you would need to disable `query_rewrite` for the session if you wanted to prevent the query plans from referencing materialized views if those materialized views were not specifically part of the query.

If, for each query, you do an

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <<the query>>
```

you can then

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_owner, object_name, object_type
  FROM plan_table
```

to get the list of objects.  If `OBJECT_TYPE` is like `INDEX%`, you can then use the `DBA_INDEXES` view (or `ALL_INDEXES` or `USER_INDEXES` depending on who owns the objects in question and what level of privileges you have) to determine what table that index is defined on

```
SELECT table_owner, table_name
  FROM dba_indexes
 WHERE owner = <<object_owner from plan_table>>
   AND index_name = <<object_name from plan_table>>
```

So, for example, if I have a view `view_1`

```
 create or replace view view_1
 as
 select *
   from emp join dept using (deptno)
```

and a query

```
select * from view_1;
```

I can do

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from view_1;

Explained.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1      SELECT distinct object_owner, object_name, object_type
  2*       FROM plan_table
SQL> /

OBJECT_OWNER                   OBJECT_NAME               OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ ------------------------- -------------------------

SCOTT                          DEPT                      TABLE
SCOTT                          PK_DEPT                   INDEX (UNIQUE)
SCOTT                          EMP                       TABLE
```

This tells me that the query is actually hitting the `EMP` and `DEPT` tables.  It is also hitting the `PK_DEPT` index so I can look to see what table that is defined on.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1      SELECT table_owner, table_name
  2        FROM dba_indexes
  3       WHERE owner = 'SCOTT'
  4*        AND index_name = 'PK_DEPT'
SQL> /

TABLE_OWNER                    TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SCOTT                          DEPT
```

As it turns out, that index is defined on the `DEPT` table as well, so I know that only the `EMP` and `DEPT` tables in the `SCOTT` schema are going to be involved in the query.

Comment: That sounds great. But I am not an Oracle guy. Can you recommend the PLAN_TABLE query i should use and how? Thanks!

Comment: @user836087 - Updated with an example.

Comment: @justin-cave Note that doing an Explain Plan on queries involving other schemas may run into permission problems - but I've been doing this where possible. Otherwise, I have a pyparsing parser that routinely runs into problems. It's a major headache to maintain