# Oracle 10g - Get list of tables from query i'm executing

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, oracle10g

I am working on internal tools of my organization, I have a automation need currently.

**Example input query:**

```
Select name,userid,url,address_line_1 from user join address on 
user.user_id = address.user_id where userid = 'xxyy';
```

what I need is list of tables

```
user
address
```

Is there a built in way in Oracle 10G to get the list of tables from this query? Or Is there a python parser that can help me with the list of tables from the query?

Note: This is a basic example, my queries run in several lines and are more complex.

Comment: Is the above query a view (or stored as an object in oracle)?  if so you can use the system tables and look at all_dependencies for the view `Select Referenced_Name from all_Dependencies where name = 'ViewName' and referenced_Type='TABLE'`

Comment: @xQbert it is not a view, it is a query in the code

Comment: something like this other answer then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366096/parse-table-names-from-a-bunch-sql-statements.  I think all that you really need is to loop through these two things: `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <<the query>>`
you can then

`SELECT DISTINCT object_owner, object_name, object_type
  FROM plan_table`

Comment: @xQbert I guess it is a little close. I'll try automate that from Python, thanks for pointing me in that direction

Comment: I'm inclined to believe the DB engine parser would be more adept at identifying all the tables involved than anything we could write/parse ourselves; thus why I went to system tables or DB engine tools.

Comment: @xQbert I have not had luck with that one, It does not bring all the tables in the query unfortunately. I tried joining my table with data with that of the table that contain statuses(about 20 statuses), the plan did not get anything about the statuses table. It would have been a perfect solution though.

Comment: if the table is not refered in the plan, than oracle use indexes to select all the data needed, you can join the all_indexes view to determine the table name

Comment: Be aware that there isn't necessarily a perfect correlation between tables in a SQL statement and tables in the query plan.  A statement might reference tables that the optimizer can eliminate.  A statement might be rewritten to use a materialized view rather than a table.  Probably not something that is likely to affect your environment too often but something to be aware of.  If you reference views and you want to get the names of those views, the plan wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still waiting for the solution, but, for now, I came up with a quick and dirty way to get the table names along with aliases using the following python.

```
    from copy import deepcopy

    import cx_Oracle


    ############################################################################
    ####################### Database connection instantiation###################
    ############################################################################

    #connObj = pyodbc.connect(connString,autocommit=True)

    qry = """
                Select name,userid,url,address_line_1 from user join address on 
user.user_id = address.user_id where userid = 'xxyy'
            """


    def getConn():
        connObj = cx_Oracle.connect('asap', 'sdfssa', cx_Oracle.makedsn('DBLDEV03', 1521, '23432'))
        return connObj

    def destroy(connObj):
        connObj.commit()
        connObj.close()

        del connObj
    #####################       Logic  ########################################
    import datetime

    def getTablesFromQuery(qry):
        listTables = []
        listAliases = []
        connObj = getConn()
        cursor = connObj.cursor()
        listSpaceItems = qry.split(" ")
        found =False
        for spaceItem in listSpaceItems:
            if spaceItem != '' and spaceItem!='\n':
                spaceItem = spaceItem.replace("\n",'')
                listCommaItems = spaceItem.split(",")
                if found == True:
                    ##### We are assuming that the next item is always alias, the sql query should follow that rule to
                    ##### get the aliases properly.
                    listAliases.append(spaceItem)
                    found = False

                for commaItem in listCommaItems:
                    if commaItem != '':
                        item = commaItem

                        if "." in commaItem:
                            item=commaItem.split(".")[1]


                        cursor.execute('select * from all_tables where table_name=\''+item.upper()+'\'')
                        res = cursor.fetchall()
                        if res is not None and res.__len__()>0:
                            listTables.append(commaItem)
                            found = True
        destroy(connObj)
        return listTables,listAliases

    try:
        listTables, listAliases = getTablesFromQuery(qry)
        for item in listTables:
            print(''+item)

    except:
        print('Exception..')


############################################################################
####################### close database connection###########################
############################################################################
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

You could build a little SQL analyzer in PL/SQL using `DBMS_FGA`.  The idea would be:

- Automatically modify the input SQL to also use a table with a FGA policy on it
- In that FGA policy, you will have access to the current SQL (the first 32K of it, anyway.  That's a limitation...)
- Use the current SQL to build a throw-away view on the current SQL
- Read the throw-away view's dependencies from `USER_DEPENDENCIES`
- Drop the throw-away view.

Here is an example of how it would work:

(I apologize for putting my first name in all the objects; I share this database with others.)

```
-- Tester
BEGIN
   matt_analysis_pkg.analyze_sql(p_sql => 
      'WITH oel AS ( SELECT * 
                     FROM oe_order_lines 
                     WHERE ship_from_org_id = 88 ) 
      SELECT oel.line_id, msi.segment1 
      FROM oel INNER JOIN mtl_system_items msi 
         ON msi.organization_id = 92 and msi.inventory_item_id = oel.inventory_item_id');
END;
/

Objects referenced by current SQL: 
APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS (SYNONYM)
APPS.OE_ORDER_LINES (SYNONYM)
```

The example (below) just reports the 1st level of dependencies.  You could use DBA_DEPENDENCIES recursively to get more depth.  Also, this version just writes to `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

As others have reported, just because a SQL depends on an object doesn't mean Oracle will actually access that object at run-time.  Still, I think this is pretty close to what you were asking for.

Also, I noticed you tagged your question with Oracle 10g.  I think the only thing in my solution that won't work in 10g is my direct access of a sequence.  You'll have to replace that part with `SELECT ... INTO` to get the current sequence value.

Anyway, here is the source code for it (Oracle 12c):

```
-- This table doesn't do anything other than have a FGA policy on it.
CREATE TABLE matt_analysis_tab ( dummy varchar2(1) );

INSERT INTO matt_analysis_tab (dummy) VALUES ('X');

-- Sequence so we can create unique view names, in case two people analyze at the same time.
CREATE SEQUENCE matt_analysis_view_s;

-- Package to do the work.
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE matt_analysis_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE analyze_sql ( p_sql CLOB );
  PROCEDURE analyze_current_sql (schema_name VARCHAR2, table_name VARCHAR2, policy_name VARCHAR2);
END matt_analysis_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY matt_analysis_pkg AS

  PROCEDURE analyze_sql (p_sql CLOB) IS
    l_modified_sql CLOB := 'WITH v1$ AS ( SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ dummy FROM matt_analysis_tab ) SELECT v1$.dummy, v2$.* FROM v1$, ( ' || p_sql || ') v2$';
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_modified_sql := ' || l_modified_sql);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_modified_sql;
  END analyze_sql;


  PROCEDURE analyze_current_sql (schema_name VARCHAR2, table_name VARCHAR2, policy_name VARCHAR2) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    l_sql CLOB;    
    l_column_count          INTEGER;
    l_view_name VARCHAR2(30);
    l_view_columns   VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    l_sql := SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL',4000) 
    || SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL1',4000)
    || SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL2',4000)
    || SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL3',4000)
    || SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL4',4000)
    || SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL5',4000)
    || SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL6',4000)
    || SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'CURRENT_SQL7',4000)
    ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Current SQL: ' || l_sql);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Current SQL length (calc): ' || length(l_sql));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Current SQL length (userenv): ' || SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','CURRENT_SQL_LENGTH'));

    -- Parse the SQL to get the column count
    DECLARE
  l_cursor                INTEGER;
  l_column_descriptions   SYS.DBMS_SQL.desc_tab;

  BEGIN
    l_cursor   := sys.DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;

  -- parse SQL
  sys.DBMS_SQL.parse (c => l_cursor, statement => l_sql, language_flag => sys.DBMS_SQL.native);

  -- Describe columns
  sys.DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (c => l_cursor, col_cnt => l_column_count, desc_t => l_column_descriptions);

  sys.DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (l_cursor);

END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column count = ' || l_column_count);

  -- Build view columns.  We need to do this because the column names in the SQL are not necessarily unique.    
  SELECT listagg('C' || lpad(rownum,4,'0'),',') within group ( order by rownum )
  INTO    l_view_columns 
  FROM   dual 
  CONNECT BY rownum <= l_column_count;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_view_columns = ' || l_view_columns);

  l_view_name := 'matt_analysis_view_' || lpad(matt_analysis_view_s.nextval,6,'0') || '$';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_view_name = ' || l_view_name);

  l_sql := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW ' || l_view_name || ' (' || l_view_columns || ') AS ' || l_sql;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objects referenced by current SQL: ');
  FOR r IN ( select referenced_owner || '.' || referenced_name || ' (' || referenced_type || ')' reference_info 
             from user_dependencies where name = upper(l_view_name)
             AND  referenced_name not like 'MATT_ANALYSIS%' ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.reference_info);
  END LOOP;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP VIEW ' || l_view_name;

  COMMIT;

  END analyze_current_sql;
END matt_analysis_pkg;
/

-- Create the FGA policy 
BEGIN
  DBMS_FGA.add_policy (
    object_schema     => NULL,  -- My current schema
    object_name       => 'MATT_ANALYSIS_TAB',
    policy_name       => 'MATT_ANALYSIS_POLICY',
    audit_condition   => NULL,
    audit_column      => NULL,
    handler_schema    => NULL,  -- My current schema
    handler_module    => 'matt_analysis_pkg.analyze_current_sql',
    enable            => TRUE);
END;
/

-- Script to drop the policy, just in case
--EXEC  DBMS_FGA.drop_policy (NULL, 'MATT_ANALYSIS_TAB', 'MATT_ANALYSIS_POLICY');
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, i'll try this.

Comment: Actually, you could do without all the FGAC stuff.  Just have `ANALYZE_SQL` build the view and all that.  The FGAC approach was from something else.  I can post a simplified version if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a package procedure to accept a SQL statement as input.  What it would do is wrap the SQL in a `CREATE VIEW` and then analyze the dependencies of the resulting view.

Here is the source code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE matt_analysis_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE analyze_sql ( p_sql CLOB );
END matt_analysis_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY matt_analysis_pkg AS

  PROCEDURE analyze_sql (p_sql CLOB) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    l_sql CLOB;    
    l_column_count          INTEGER;
    l_view_name VARCHAR2(30);
    l_view_columns   VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Current SQL: ' || p_sql);

    -- Parse the SQL to get the column count
    DECLARE
  l_cursor                INTEGER;
  l_column_descriptions   SYS.DBMS_SQL.desc_tab;

  BEGIN
    l_cursor   := sys.DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;

  -- parse SQL
  sys.DBMS_SQL.parse (c => l_cursor, statement => p_sql, language_flag => sys.DBMS_SQL.native);

  -- Describe columns
  sys.DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (c => l_cursor, col_cnt => l_column_count, desc_t => l_column_descriptions);

  sys.DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (l_cursor);

END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column count = ' || l_column_count);

  -- Build view columns.  We need to do this because the column names in the SQL are not necessarily unique.    
  SELECT listagg('C' || lpad(rownum,4,'0'),',') within group ( order by rownum )
  INTO    l_view_columns 
  FROM   dual 
  CONNECT BY rownum <= l_column_count;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_view_columns = ' || l_view_columns);

  l_view_name := 'matt_analysis_view_' || lpad(matt_analysis_view_s.nextval,6,'0') || '$';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_view_name = ' || l_view_name);

  l_sql := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW ' || l_view_name || ' (' || l_view_columns || ') AS ' || p_sql;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Objects referenced by current SQL: ');
  FOR r IN ( select referenced_owner || '.' || referenced_name || ' (' || referenced_type || ')' reference_info 
             from user_dependencies where name = upper(l_view_name)
             AND  referenced_name not like 'MATT_ANALYSIS%' ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.reference_info);
  END LOOP;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP VIEW ' || l_view_name;

  COMMIT;

  END analyze_sql;
END matt_analysis_pkg;
/
```

#### Tester

```
BEGIN
   matt_analysis_pkg.analyze_sql(p_sql => 
      'WITH oel AS ( SELECT * 
                     FROM oe_order_lines 
                     WHERE ship_from_org_id = 88 ) 
      SELECT oel.line_id, msi.segment1 
      FROM oel INNER JOIN mtl_system_items msi 
         ON msi.organization_id = 92 and msi.inventory_item_id = oel.inventory_item_id');
END;

Objects referenced by current SQL: 
APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS (SYNONYM)
APPS.OE_ORDER_LINES (SYNONYM)
```